# HTML select control containing HTML and JavaScript tags as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a select control getting values dynamically.
In the script, I need to insert the following text inside the select tags as its inner html.

```
<option value=""></option>
<option><h1>zoot</h1></option>
<option><div>divTest</div></option>
<option><span> style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">SpanTest</span></option>
<option><option>option</optipon></option>
```

What I am trying to do is in the picture below
[image]

I tried using HTMLEncode and that was not working too. Am I able to do this using JavaScript or jQuery or by any other means in html select control ?

Comment: "_I tried using HTMLEncode_" Can you also post the code that you have tried.

Comment: Please add your code you used to make dynamic content

Comment: You shouldn't put html into `<option>` elements, your best bet would be CSS or showing a list instead

Comment: As stated by @BenKolyaMansley there are many plugins available that implement a select on their own, due to the various short comings of native the `select` html element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It you want the HTML to be user-visible, you need to encode it. Working example below.

```html
<select name="example">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option>&lt;h1&gt;zoot&lt;/h1&gt;</option>
  <option>&lt;div&gt;divTest&lt;/div&gt;</option>
  <option>&lt;span&gt; style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">SpanTest&lt;/span&gt;</option>
  <option>&lt;option&gt;option&lt;/optipon&gt;</option>
 </select>
```

If you are trying to show previews using those HTML blocks, you may wish to drop out of `select` lists and provide a different user interface to do so - such as previews combined with radio inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the items to the select using jQuery and the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function.

e.g.

```js
var vals = ["<h1>zoot</h1>",
  "<div>divTest</div>",
  "<span> style='color:red;font-weight:bold;'>SpanTest</span>",
  "",
  "option"
];

var $stuff = $("#stuff");

vals.forEach(function(val) {
  $("<option/>").text(val).appendTo($stuff);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="stuff">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>
```